# Como enviar informações para uma api em json Delphi 7, Por favor me ajudem

Tags: delphi

Utilizando o Delphi 7 como enviar informações a uma API ao clicar em um botão fechar?

Os dados enviados seria um JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um exemplo como enviar Json a um WebService

Adicione o componente tIDHTTP da Indy ao seu form e no seu evento envie da 
seguinte forma:

```
var
  Json: string;
  sResponse: string;
  JsonToSend: TStringStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin

   LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
   idHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;

   try

   Json := '{ '+
              ' "email":"meuemail@gmail.com",'+
              ' "sistema":"meusistema",'+
              ' "cdemp":"codigo"'+
              ' } ';
   JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(Json, TEncoding.UTF8);
   sResponse := IdHTTP.Post('http://url:porta/api/sistema/esqueciasenha', JsonToSend);


     except
           on e  : Exception  do
           begin
           end;
        end;

      finally
        JsonToSend.Free;
      end;


    end;

   LHandler.Free;

end;
```

Comment: LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL; preciso utilizar alguma calsse em especifica ?

Comment: Adicione a sua clausula Uses IdSSLOpenSSL

Comment: Reginaldo, tem alguma outra forma de contato ?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a biblioteca a Indy,

Muito simples, veja:

```
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  vJsonAEnviar: TStringStream;
begin
  HTTP:= TIdHTTP.Create;
  HTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';

  HTTP.Get('endereco\api\dados={json}');    
  //ou
  vJsonAEnviar := TStringStream.Create(UTF8Encode('{json}'));
  HTTP.Post('endereco', vJsonAEnviar);
  FreeAndNil(HTTP);
  FreeAndNil(vJsonAEnviar);
end;
```

Fonte: [Site Oficial do Projeto Indy](https://www.indyproject.org/)

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar!